# Animation in chrome via Mobirise glitches

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mobirise

I'm new to Stack, html and mobirise and (insert anything).
So, I bought a template in Mobirise, built a website [Skystreem](https://skystreem.com), but have 1 problem, animation in blocks doesn't work in Chrome or any webkit browsers, works in Edge and Safari. (especially that part "section class="counters1").
So, I tried to explore it and found this: For example,
1) if I add 2 blocks and then counter animation block - it doesnt count, just shows numbers.
2) if I add all the same, but counter block is first - it does animate in chrome.

I tried to check source code, but it is exactly the same and using the same assets, just sections' places (header2-h and counters1-d) are switched places.

Also there you can find the code itself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Hi -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/icons/icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/animate.css/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css">
  <link href="assets/fonts/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/skystreem/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">



</head>

<body>
  <section class="mbr-section article content1 cid-qA7BcRsr7c" id="content1-g" data-rv-view="229">



    <div class="container">
      <div class="media-container-row">
        <div class="mbr-text col-12 col-md-12">
          <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style block-title align-center display-2">Siz əldə edirsiniz</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



  <section class="header2 cid-qA7BfwvgVH" id="header2-h" data-rv-view="233">





    <div class="container">
      <div class="media-container-row">
        <div class="media-content">
          <h1 class="mbr-section-title mbr-white pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-1">Bu nədir?</h1>
          <div class="mbr-section-text mbr-white pb-3 ">
            <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-5"><strong>SkyStreem </strong>– Azərbaycanda çalışan şirkətlər üçün unikal marketinq xidmətidir.<br><br>Təsəvvür edin, müştəri məkanınızda WiFi şəbəkənizə qoşulur və Siz onun Facebook/Instagram profili, onun adı, yaşı, ad günü və bütün digər
              dəyərli ictimai məlumatlarını icazəsi ilə avtomatik əldə edirsiniz!
              <br><br>Bizimlə bu <strong>artıq mümkündür</strong>!</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="mbr-figure" style="width: 100%;">
          <img src="assets/images/pic3-6881x5681.jpg" alt="SkyStreem" title="" media-simple="true">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="counters1 counters cid-qA7ADWZ6ht" id="counters1-d" data-rv-view="230">


    <div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.7; background-color: rgb(4, 54, 124);">
    </div>

    <div class="container mbr-white">



      <div class="container pt-4 mt-2">
        <div class="media-container-row">
          <div class="card p-3 align-center col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel-item p-3">


              <div class="card-text">
                <h3 class="count pt-3 pb-3 mbr-semibold mbr-fonts-style display-1">
                  166
                </h3>
                <h4 class="mbr-content-title mbr-semibold pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                  Clients
                </h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="card p-3 align-center col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel-item p-3">

              <div class="card-text">
                <h3 class="count pt-3 pb-3 mbr-semibold mbr-fonts-style display-1">
                  210
                </h3>
                <h4 class="mbr-content-title mbr-semibold pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                  Projects
                </h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card p-3 align-center col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel-item p-3">

              <div class="card-text">
                <h3 class="count pt-3 pb-3 mbr-semibold mbr-fonts-style display-1">
                  357
                </h3>
                <h4 class="mbr-content-title mbr-semibold pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                  Testimonials
                </h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/viewport-checker/jquery.viewportchecker.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>


  <div id="scrollToTop" class="scrollToTop mbr-arrow-up"><a style="text-align: center;"><i class="mbri-down mbr-iconfont"></i></a></div>
  <input name="animation" type="hidden">
</body>

</html>
```

I will be very grateful to anyone who helps even a little bit.
Thank y'all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in last versions Mobirise often has this problem in different themes. I solved this issue with moving the script. Maybe you would also find an answer somewhere here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.